# Algorithm to scale down YUV 4:2:2

Tags: c#, algorithm, video

Trying to write an efficient algorithm to scale down YUV 4:2:2 by a factor of 2 - and which doesn't require a conversion to RGB (which is CPU intensive).

I've seen plenty of code on stack overflow for YUV to RGB conversion - but only an example of scaling for YUV 4:2:0 here which I have started based my code on.  However, this produces an image which is effectively 3 columns of the same image with corrupt colours, so something is wrong with the algo when applied to 4:2:2.

Can anybody see what is wrong with this code?

```
public static byte[] HalveYuv(byte[] data, int imageWidth, int imageHeight)
{
    byte[] yuv = new byte[imageWidth / 2 * imageHeight / 2 * 3 / 2];

    int i = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y += 2)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += 2)
        {
            yuv[i] = data[y * imageWidth + x];
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight / 2; y += 2)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += 4)
        {
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + x];
            i++;
            yuv[i] = data[(imageWidth * imageHeight) + (y * imageWidth) + (x + 1)];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return yuv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fast way to generate a low quality thumbnail would be to discard half of the data in each dimension.

We break the image in 4x2 grid of pixels - each pair of pixels in the grid is represented by 4 bytes. In the down-scaled image, we take the color values for the first 2 pixels in the grid by copying the first 4 bytes, whilst discarding the other 12 bytes worth of data.

This scaling can be generalized to any power of 2 (1/2, 1/4, 1/8, ...) - this method is quick because it doesn't use any interpolation. This will give a lower quality image which appears blocky however - for better results consider some sampling approach.

```
public static byte[] FastResize(
    byte[] data, 
    int imageWidth, 
    int imageHeight, 
    int scaleDownExponent)
{
    var scaleDownFactor = (uint)Math.Pow(2, scaleDownExponent);

    var outputImageWidth = imageWidth / scaleDownFactor;
    var outputImageHeight = imageHeight / scaleDownFactor;
    // 2 bytes per pixel.
    byte[] yuv = new byte[outputImageWidth * outputImageHeight * 2];

    var pos = 0;
    // Process every other line.
    for (uint pixelY = 0; pixelY < imageHeight; pixelY += scaleDownFactor)
    { 
        // Work in blocks of 2 pixels, we discard the second.
        for (uint pixelX = 0; pixelX < imageWidth; pixelX += 2*scaleDownFactor)
        {
            // Position of pixel bytes.
            var start = ((pixelY * imageWidth) + pixelX) * 2;

            yuv[pos] = data[start];
            yuv[pos + 1] = data[start + 1];
            yuv[pos + 2] = data[start + 2];
            yuv[pos + 3] = data[start + 3];

            pos += 4;
        }
    }

    return yuv;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the original data is in the following order (as it seems so from your example code): First there are the  luminance (Y) values of the pixels of the image (`size = imageWidth*imageHeight` bytes). After that there are the chrominance components UV, s.t., the values for a single pixel are given after each other. This means that the total size of the original image is `3*size`.

Now for 4:2:2 subsampling means that every other value of the horizontal chrominance component are discarded. This reduces the data to size `size + 0.5*size + 0.5*size = 2*size`, i.e., luminance is kept completely and both chrominance components are divided to half. Therefore, the result image should be allocated as:

```
byte[] yuv = new byte[2*imageWidth*imageHeight];
```

As the first part of the image is copied in full the first loop becomes:

```
int i = 0;
for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x++)
    {
        yuv[i] = data[y * imageWidth + x];
        i++;
    }
}
```

Because this just copies the beginning of data this can be simplified to

```
int size = imageHeight*imageWidth;
int i = 0;
for (; i < size; i++)
{
    yuv[i] = data[i];
}
```

Now to copy the rest we need to skip every other horizontal coordinate

```
for (int y = 0; y < imageHeight; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < imageWidth; x += 2) // +2 skip each other horizontal component
    {
        yuv[i] = data[size + y*2*imageWidth + 2*x]; 
        i++;
        yuv[i] = data[size + y*2*imageWidth + 2*x + 1];
        i++;
    }
}
```

The factor two in `data`-array index is needed because there are 2 bytes for each pixel (both chrominance components), so each "row" has `2*imageWidth` bytes of data.